# How to get curl exit status from sh step command?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to get the result of a command into a boolean variable in my Jenkinsfile. The command is: `curl -o/dev/null -sfI "$url"`, which can be used in sh like this:

```
if ( curl -o/dev/null -sfI "$url" ); then
  echo "URL exists"
else
  echo "URL does not exist"
fi
```

So, I need this condition in my jenkinsfile but I don't know how to recreate it. This is what I've tried:

```
def fileAlreadyExists = sh(
                script: "curl -o/dev/null -sfI \"$url\"",
                returnStdout: true
        )
```

But seems to return false always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command does not return any output due to `-o /dev/null` switch. If you want to catch exit code you would have to set `returnStatus` and not `returnStdout` option, like:

```groovy
def fileAlreadyExists = sh(
            script: "curl -o/dev/null -sfI \"$url\"",
            returnStatus: true
)
```

Alternatively you could extend your Bash command to do `echo $?` after the curl command to echo last command exit code:

```groovy
def fileAlreadyExists = sh(
            script: "curl -o/dev/null -sfI \"$url\"; echo \\\$?",
            returnStdout: true
) as Integer // explicit casting needed, because it returns String
```

The variable `fileAlreadyExists` stores an integer value, so you can use it in `if ()` statement (Groovy evalutes `if (0)` to `false`, so if you expect `0` exit code then it is good idea to make this comparison explicit like:

```
if (fileAlreadyExists == 0) { /* exists */ } else { /* not exist */ }
```

As a side note: remember to escape `\` if you want to pass it to the sh command - Jenkins strips single escape character, so if you want to pass e.g. double quote the underlying script then you have to escape it in the following way: `\\\"`.